# Maven Failed to Execute goal maven-assembly-plugin

Tags: maven

I am running **mvn clean install** on an old project.  I get this error, and don't really even understand  it.   This project builds a executable jar.  I am kind of lost on how to interpret.  This is an older project that was working.

[image]

Comment: I suppose you are using Java 7..which means you have to define `https.protocols=TLSv1.2` cause for a longer time Central only supports TLSv1.2 and not TLSv1.1 anymore...and that's the reason why you can't download things. Furthermore the version you are using is extremely old...please use a more recent version in your pom as already mentioned.

Comment: You commented the '...version of  What..is very old...'?  This is a Spring Batch project I"m' transferring  to a new laptop.  Am happy to do that.  What do you see as 'very old?'  Am mildly worried about making wholesale version upgrades will throw the project into other exception headaches.... Nervous about introducing in too many at once.  Thanks for your help too.

Comment: My comment was not accurate enough. I referenced to the maven-assembly-plugin version....